# Getting Unique Visitors From google analytics php interface (gapi)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, visitors

I'm using the code :

```
function get_indiv_visitors($site_id, $start_date, $end_date=NULL) {
        require 'config.php';
        $ga = new gapi($ga_email,$ga_password);
        $ga->requestReportData($site_id, array('pagePath'),array('Visitors'),         $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, $start_date, $end_date);
        $totalvisitors = $ga->getVisitors();
        return $totalvisitors;
}
```

This code works, but returns a number that is greater than visits (which I cross references with the google analytics sites, so those numbers are definitely correct). It doesn't make sense that I should have more visitors than visits.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how GA tracks visits and visitors:

> The visit is assigned to the first page but not subsequent pages, whereas unique visitors are assigned to each page

See [Unique visitors, 0 visits and pages in web analytics](http://www.michaelwhitaker.com/blog/2010/04/23/unique-visitors-0-visits-and-pages-in-web-analytics/)

Answer (score 1):

change the dimension to 'userDefinedValue'

```
function get_indiv_visitors($site_id, $start_date, $end_date=NULL) {
        require 'config.php';
        $ga = new gapi($ga_email,$ga_password);
        $ga->requestReportData($site_id, array('userDefinedValue'),array('Visitors'),            $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, $start_date, $end_date);
        $totalvisitors = $ga->getVisitors();
        return $totalvisitors;
}
```